# Python Postgres return result when it is none

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was wondering if i used psycopg2 library(for postgres sql) for python, what will be the return result if my query was supposed to none. Null, none, blank or anything else? Thanks in advance

Comment: Y dont you try yourself and test? what it results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL NULL maps to Python None, if that's what you mean:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT NULL")

>>> cursor.fetchall()
[(None,)]
```

If you mean an empty resultset, you'll get an empty list if you use `fetchall()` on a cursor:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE 1=2")

>>> cursor.fetchall()
[]
```

Or if you're iterating over the cursor, you'll just get no results.

Comment: Thank you! the empty resultset was what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try?
With mysql it returns empty tuple, probably here is the same